How to keep Python main module running while Serial Output goes to a display
I've been working on this project on and off for a while; for the most part, it does exactly what I want it to do. I'm using an RPI Zero with a TFLUNA lidar sensor and SSD1306 type display for range outputs.
The issue I am running into is that I want the ranging function to run at all times with no pause, the pause occurs when the 'distance' read goes to the physical display(SSD1306), during this time, if the distance < 1 is true; the subprocess does not run, or runs after the display output has been written.
I've considered moving the display output to its own function linked to a physical pushbutton to possibly eliminate the pausing, as I don't always need the range to be displayed — or another subprocess?, but I’d like to at least know the cause of the delay.
-- I have taken and modified project code from another source, I believe from https://github.com/makerportal/tfluna-python/blob/main/tfluna_realtime.py --
Project Code mixed with modifications:
import serial,time
import subprocess
from time import sleep
from luma.core.interface.serial import i2c
from luma.oled.device import ssd1306
from luma.core.virtual import terminal
import threading as th

serial1 = i2c(port=1, address=0x3c)
device = ssd1306(serial1)
term = terminal(device)
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/serial0", 115200,timeout=0)

def main():

    def read_tfluna_data():
        while True:
            counter = ser.in_waiting
            if counter > 8:
                bytes_serial = ser.read(9)
                ser.reset_input_buffer()

                if bytes_serial[0] == 0x59 and bytes_serial[1] == 0x59:
                    distance = bytes_serial[2] + bytes_serial[3]*256
                    strength = bytes_serial[4] + bytes_serial[5]*256
                    temperature = bytes_serial[6] + bytes_serial[7]*256
                    temperature = (temperature/8.0) - 256.0
                    return distance/100.0

    if ser.isOpen() == False:
        ser.open()
    distance = read_tfluna_data()
    print('{0:2.2f} m' .\
        format(distance))
    term.puts('\n\n\t\t{0:2.2f} m' .\
        format(distance))
    term.clear()

    if distance < 1:
        subprocess.Popen('raspistill -t 100 -o `date +%d%m%Y_%H%M-%S` .\
            jpg;sleep 5', shell=True)
        ser.close()

time = 1
while True:
    main()
    time +=1

